# What is wrong with my tomato plants? The stems are browning from root

Tags: diseases, tomatoes

I don't know much about gardening. Just started a little rooftop garden during quarantine. I noticed some of my tomato plants were browning from the soil. It looks like the brown parts are not getting thicker but the rest of the plant does. Today while I was checking my plants one of the tomato plant just snapped like a dry branch. It had a lot of flowers and it got me worrying about my other plants.

This started a couple weeks ago, I saw a small insect/mite on one of the plant immediately took the photo and showed it to the place where I got the plants. He gave me a spraying solution and said it would both kill the mites and heal the brown plants. I dont see mites anymore but the browning issue is getting worse.

I water them daily and live in a sunny place and my plants get direct sunlight until 2-3pm.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://homeguides.sfgate.com/repair-overwatered-tomato-plants-54639.html

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Alternaria Stem Canker](https://www2.ipm.ucanr.edu/agriculture/tomato/Alternaria-Stem-Canker/). Not good news I'm afraid. The vine is basically toast since the canker will girdle the stem and shut down all movement of sap. Since the canker is at the base this indicates the spores were in the soil and moved up to the plant. Remove affected plants as soon as possible and destroy, make sure not to use the soil for susceptible plants such as potato, tomato and brassicas. Make sure to use Alternaria resistant varieties of tomato in your garden in future since you know the disease is present.